# Firebase complex queries

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to build an app with Firebase. The app is a dating app, so I will need an ability to make complex data queries from the database. For example, I will need to query Men, 25-35, from New-York, 172 tall, not smoking. I understand how to do this in SQL, but in Firebase, I'm completely new.

Can someone be so kind and show me the way of performing such queries?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Query based on multiple where clauses in firebase](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26700924/query-based-on-multiple-where-clauses-in-firebase)

Comment: Specify your programming language, and your JSON tree(expected).